# Align picture so it doesnt wrap under nav list.

Tags: html, css

I'm working on the CSS file for a beginner's Internet Programming course I am taking. The problem is that whenever I made the image in the section into a link, it screwed up the alignment with the rest of the section. I have a Nav List on the side above where this image is, and the Image and Link below it are aligning under the nav bar, while everything else below THAT are staying aligned.

Here is the code:

```
<p>If you click on the Personal link, you can browse my favorite Halloween pictures, 
    stories, and films. And if you join my email list, I will keep you up-to-date on 
    all things Halloween.</p>
<h2>Product of the Week</h2>
  <a href="products/cat.html">
         <img src="images/cat1.jpg" alt="20'' Deranged Cat">
  </a>
  <br>
  <a href="products/cat.html">20" Deranged Cat</a>
  <h2>My guarantee</h2>
  <p>If you aren't completely satisfied with everything you buy from my site, you can return it 
    for a full refund. 
  <strong>No questions asked!</strong></p>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
 /* Section */
section 
{
    margin: 20px 25px 25px 25px;
}

section h1 
{ 
    font-size: 150%;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    margin-left: 200px;
}

section h1:first-letter 
{ 
    font-size: 250%;
}

section h2 
{
    font-size: 125%;
    margin: .8em 0 .5em 0;
    margin-left: 200px;
}

section p 
{
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    margin-left: 200px;
}

/*Formatting for added Product of Week Request in Section 6 Bullet 4*/
/*Changed for Section 7, Bullet 3*/
section img a
{
    margin: 300px;
}

section a
{
    display: inline;
}

/* Footer */
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: [Pasted into JSFiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/T7m2n/)

Comment: Err, how do you expect it to align?

Comment: Give him a break. He did say he's a beginner. Instruct and educate, and keep the sarcasm out. It's disrespectful to him as a student and to the field of computer science and development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damann23, welcome to SO...to align items you have to get familiar with several properties such as

```
float:left;
display:inline;
```

I put your code in a fiddle and although it needs work, this coould give you an idea of how to start. But remember, organizing your code in sections (divs) it's always a smart thing to do instead of running everything in a sheet. That way you can manage these sections individually

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4R7wy/1/)

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, which worked well! However, now, the br tag I added to drop the link underneath the image isn't working, which I assume is because br doesn't work except on free text. Further, my h2 and p elements underneath are wrapping to the right of the image/link. Any suggestions? I've posted the full code in a fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/Damann23/jFV4U/

Comment: The fiddle doesn't show the full extent of the wrapping, but you'll get the picture.

Comment: This is where you get familiar with the margins and padding properties. They help you line things up/ I put the styles inline so you can see which element they should affect, but you should try to put all your styles in the css instead of inline styling [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jFV4U/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what it is you are trying to do but if you are trying to have them both on the same line you could wrap the text in a span tag and place the image and text in the a tag like so...

check the updated fiddle [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T7m2n/1/)

```
<a href="products/cat.html">
    <img src="images/cat1.jpg" alt="Cat">
    <span>20" Deranged Cat</span>
 </a>
```